# How to turn list of arrays into dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, function

I have a list of arrays:

```
[array([10,20,30]), array([5,6,7])]
```

How to turn it into pandas dataframe? pd.DataFrame() puts arrays in on column. desired result is:

```
0     1    2
10    20   30
5     6    7
```

0 1 2 here are column names

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? `pd.DataFrame(array_list)` seems to work for me in 1.4.0.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame( [array([10,20,30]), array([5,6,7])] )` gives me expected result. What code did you use?

Comment: @fsimonjetz error says numpy.float64 object is not iterable

Comment: @furas error says numpy.float64 object is not iterable

Comment: show full error and code which generate this problem - with current description this question is only waste of time. Code works for us but you have some problem because probably you run something different  - and we can't see it (and we can't read in your mind) - so we can only downvote or close it.

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = [np.array([10,20,30]), np.array([5,6,7])]
print(pd.DataFrame(a))
```

Comment: error says numpy.float64 object is not iterable

Comment: @Ir8_mind I will repeat - show FULL error message in your question and code which you run. Maybe you assigned something else to variables and now they make problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put the **np** before the array.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

list = [np.array([10,20,30]), np.array([5,6,7])]
df = pd.DataFrame(list)
print(df)
```

output:

```
    0   1   2
0  10  20  30
1   5   6   7
```

If you still get an error, is the list of arrays a result from previous data manipulation or did you manually type out the values / array lists?